# Recorder app for iPhone

Tags: ios

I am searching for an app for iPhone which enables me to record university lectures.

When I try to use the built-in recorder, I can hear a lot of noise, so the quality of the audio is really low.

So I am wondering if there's a better app which can erase the background noise

Comment: I hope you don't sleep in the lectures

Comment: It's because I am always sleepy that i need it!

Comment: Any luck with this so far? A trick to reduce the noise is to cover the microphone/phone with something fluffy like a small towel or a fluffy sock or something similar.

Comment: That would be nice if it include captions or subtitles since I am deaf and I am trying to find similar one for conversation with another person.